# How to access Web app DOM window.MyCollection in electron

Tags: electron, desktop-application

I'm trying to get count number from my web application for update badge number & using electron `loadURL` to run my application.

Also, I'm using the Electron Windows Badge plugin for the badge number on the app icon in windows `electron-windows-badge`.

This is my web app code for update badge number

```
window.MyCollection.on('PENDING', (type, contactIdParams) => {

console.log(window.getBadgeCount())

})
```

I was trying to execute the below code but `ipcRenderer` unable import & `update-badge` not working inside executeJavaScript.

```
  let mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "renderer", "renderer.js"),
    }
  });


  mainWindow.loadURL("https://my-web-application.com");


  mainWindow.webContents.on('dom-ready', e => {

    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`

       window.MyCollection.on('PENDING', (type, Id) => {

          ipcRenderer.sendSync('update-badge', window.getBadgeCount());

        })

    `)

  });
```

What's the way to get this count number from my web application and update the badge number of the app icon.

Answer (score 0):

The application object was not being accessed due to a `contextIsolation:true`.